# ASP Identity FindByIdAsync implementation if I don't store Id value in my database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I have a custom UserStore implement IUserStore for my MVC5 project, but I don't save the Id value in my database. So when I implement FindByIdAsync, I just create a new instance of my TUser and pass it as result. I don't have any problem so far, but is this safe? I don't want this hack to bite me later.

My UserStore:

```
public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{

    TUser user = (TUser)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TUser));
    user.UserName = userId;
    user.Password = null;

    //I'm suppose to query the database with userId parameter here

    return Task.FromResult<TUser>(user); //return as is
}

public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    TUser user = (TUser)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TUser));
    user = usertable.GetUserByUserName(userName);

    return Task.FromResult<TUser>(user);
}
```

My Identity

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser
{

    public IdentityUser()
    {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    private string _id;
    public string Id {
        get { return _id; }
    }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE : By safe, I mean that I would have no problem implementing other UserStore interface later because when I debug my code, I found that FindByIdAsync method is getting called on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync.

Comment: *Is this safe?* Safe how? Thread safe? Unicorn Safe?

Comment: By safe, I mean that I would have no problem implementing other UserStore interface later because when I debug my code, I found that FindByIdAsync method is getting called on SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

Comment: If your Id is your username then you could just call FindByName from within FindById

Comment: Not a bad question.  I can only assume he's making a Herculean effort to not use Entity Framework but still implement ASP.NET Identity.  Unfortunately there's no best practices manual on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are very many reasons why you want to have a numerical ID in your users table (or any table). Fast indexing, fast relationship joining, uniqueness. The ID field should be meaningless (not a representation of the current date and time, not a hash of the user name, not anything but an auto-incrementing or random integer or in some cases a GUID that uses a default value of NEWSEQUENTIALID and NOT just a NEWID) except in very rare cases such as if you are using the Social Security number or Social Insurance Number (Canada) so that uniqueness is guaranteed by some other agency outside your database.

The approach you are using is not safe from a variety of problems. For one, a user should be able to change their name if it was misspelled or they get married or something. If you have a unique numerical ID then this is no problem and name changes don't matter. You NEVER want to store their identifiable credentials in a Cookie, even a session cookie but a random ID is not a violation of their privacy and security. I strongly advise you to bite the bullet and use a numerical ID on top of whatever table definition you already have. It harms nothing and helps everything.

Comment: Username is permanent and not editable so we can ignore that.

Anyway, the reason I don't use ID is because I don't have access to real database instead I was provided with web services to do register/login stuff. Details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822545/implement-asp-net-identity-iuserlockoutstore-without-iuserpasswordstore

Is there any alternative so I can use ID? I can build my own database to store user stuff but register/login must went through web services.

Comment: I would say that this is one of those cases where uniqueness IS guaranteed by some agency outside your database. So, in this case I would actually take the MD5 hash of those names as immutable IDs that will map 1 to 1 with the names. If you used a 64-bit integer consisting of just the first or last eight bytes of the 16-byte hash, then you would have 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 possible positive values so it is very unlikely that you would run into duplicate values.

Comment: Mind you, in the unusual situation you are in, I'm not actually sure you're taking any risk, except I would think over the security implications. If only trusted code can call that function and the "Name/UserID" value is only coming from a trusted source (and NOT unvalidated user input) then go with it.